# Why does this keep looping?

Tags: java, loops

The error I'm getting when I try to run my program is that it keeps looping between `turnFirstNumber()` and `turnSecondNumber()` after I go through all 3 'turns' entirely the first time.

EDIT: SEE BOTTOM.

My Test Class:

```
public class testLock
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Lock testLock = new Lock();
        testLock.turnLock();
        return;
    }
}
```

Here's my code segments causing me grief:

```
public void turnLock()
{       
  System.out.print("This is a lock that goes from 0 to 39. You must turn the knob clockwise first, then counterclockwise twice, ");
  System.out.print("then clockwise for the final input. Specify how many revolutions you want (Positive number indicates ");
  System.out.println("COUNTER CLOCKWISE. Negative number indicates CLOCKWISE.");

  turnFirstNumber();
  turnSecondNumber();
  turnThirdNumber();

    System.out.println("The combination you chose was: " + tempFirst + ", " + tempSecond + ", and " + tempThird + ".");
  return;
}
```

---

```
private boolean turnFirstNumber()
{
  revoCount = 0;
  System.out.print("11111111What is your desired direction and number of revolutions? (Positive number is counterclockwise, negative number is clockwise): ");
  count = in.nextInt();
  if (count > 0)
    isClockwise = false;
  else if (count < 0)
    isClockwise = true;
  else
  {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Your desired direction of spinning the lock is invalid. Please choose a number other than 0.");
  }
  System.out.print("\n11111111111What is your desired first number?: ");
  desiredNumber = in.nextInt();

  if (!isClockwise) //user desires countercockwise revolution
  {
    do {
      for (int i = 0; i < (count * 40); i++)
      {
        activeNumber++;
          if (activeNumber > 39)
            activeNumber = 0;
          if (activeNumber == desiredNumber)
            revoCount++;
      }
       } while ((activeNumber != desiredNumber) && (revoCount < count));
  }      
  else if (isClockwise) //user desires clockwise revolution
  {
    do {
      for (int i = 0; i < (Math.abs(count) * 40); i++)
      {
      activeNumber--;
        if (activeNumber < 0)
          activeNumber = 39;
        if (activeNumber == desiredNumber)
          revoCount++;
      }
       } while ((activeNumber != desiredNumber) && (revoCount < Math.abs(count)));
  }

  tempFirst = activeNumber;

  if ((activeNumber == first) && (count < 0)) //if first number is correct and user picked correct orientation and revolutions
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

---

```
private boolean turnSecondNumber()
{
  revoCount = 0;
  System.out.print("2222222222What is your desired direction and number of revolutions? (Positive number is counterclockwise, negative number is clockwise): ");
  count = in.nextInt();
  if (count > 0)
    isClockwise = false;
  else if (count < 0)
    isClockwise = true;
  else
  {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Your desired direction of spinning the lock is invalid. Please choose a number other than 0.");
  }
  System.out.print("\n222222222What is your desired second number?: ");
  desiredNumber = in.nextInt();

  if (!isClockwise) //user desires countercockwise revolution
  {
    do {
      for (int i = 0; i < (count * 40); i++)
      {
        activeNumber++;
          if (activeNumber > 39)
            activeNumber = 0;
          if (activeNumber == desiredNumber)
            revoCount++;
      }
       } while ((activeNumber != desiredNumber) && (revoCount < count));
  }      
  else if (isClockwise) //user desires clockwise revolution
  {
    do {
      for (int i = 0; i < (Math.abs(count) * 40); i++)
      {
      activeNumber--;
        if (activeNumber < 0)
          activeNumber = 39;
        if (activeNumber == desiredNumber)
          revoCount++;
      }
       } while ((activeNumber != desiredNumber) && (revoCount < Math.abs(count)));
  }

  tempSecond = activeNumber;

  if ((activeNumber == second) && (count == 2)) //if second number is correct and user picked correct orientation and revolutions
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

---

```
private boolean turnThirdNumber()
{
  revoCount = 0;
  System.out.print("Enter '1' to twist the dial counterclockwise until you reach your desired number. Enter '-1' to twist the dial clockwise until you reach your desired number.: ");
  count = in.nextInt();
  if (count == 1)
    isClockwise = false;
  else if (count == (-1))
    isClockwise = true;
  else
  {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("You are not supposed to do a full revolution on the third number of the combination. Now you have to restart.");
  }
  System.out.print("\n333333333What is your desired third and final number?: ");
  activeNumber = in.nextInt();
  activeNumber = Math.abs(activeNumber);
  tempThird = activeNumber;

  if (activeNumber > 39)
  {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("You desire a number that is not on the lock. The lock goes from 0 to 39. Try again.");
  }
  if ((activeNumber == third) && (isClockwise)) //if third number is correct and user picked correct orientation and revolutions
    return true;
  else    
    return false;
}
```

EDIT: So after testing more carefully, I found that my `openLock()` method may be calling my turnFirst, turnSecond, and turnThird methods somehow. I commented out my turnLock() method in my test class and ran the openLock() method and it started calling turnFirst and turnSecond multiple times and finally turnThird for some reason after a few loops. Here's the openLock():

```
public void openLock()
{ 
  if ((turnFirstNumber()) && (turnSecondNumber()) && (turnThirdNumber()) && (isClosed)) //if all 3 passed and lock is not open already
  { 
    isClosed = false;
    System.out.println("Your combination is correct and the lock has been opened.");
    return; 
  }
  else if (!isClosed)                                                        //lock's already open
  { 
    System.out.println("The lock is already open.");
    return;
  }
  else if ((!turnFirstNumber()) && (turnSecondNumber()) && (turnThirdNumber())) //first wrong
  {
    System.out.println("The first number you input is incorrect.");
    return;
  }
  else if ((!turnFirstNumber()) && (!turnSecondNumber()) && (turnThirdNumber())) //first and second wrong
  {
    System.out.println("The first 2 numbers you input are incorrect.");
    return;
  }
  else if ((!turnFirstNumber()) && (turnSecondNumber()) && (!turnThirdNumber())) //first and third wrong
  {
    System.out.println("The first and last numbers you input are incorrect.");
    return;
  }
  else if ((turnFirstNumber()) && (turnSecondNumber()) && (!turnThirdNumber())) //third wrong
  {
    System.out.println("The last number you input is incorrect.");
    return;
  }
  else if ((turnFirstNumber()) && (!turnSecondNumber()) && (!turnThirdNumber())) //second and third wrong
  {
    System.out.println("The second and last numbers you input are incorrect.");
    return;
  }
  else if ((turnFirstNumber()) && (!turnSecondNumber()) && (turnThirdNumber())) //second is wrong
  {
    System.out.println("The second number you input is incorrect.");
    return;
  }
  else
  { 
    System.out.println("Your entire combination is INCORRECT. Please try again."); //all wrong
    return; 
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that there's a lot of unnecessary code. Just narrow down the problem a little more and post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with code only related to the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to run it under debugger?

Comment: That's very bad coding style you have there. I would suggest that you separate the input from the logic. To do so, add parameters to the methods like `private boolean turnFirstNumber(int count)`

Comment: And use constants instead of hard coding numbers (e.g. `public static final int MAX_CIPHER = 40`) + add comments, so that other can understand what you thought.

Comment: There should be no constants in my program because everything can be manipulated. This is just a sample of the entire program. In the entire program, the user can change the correct combo needed to open the lock so the correct combo integers should not be FINAL, also: the user is supposed to attempt the turnLock() method and then use my openLock() method to check if their input is correct (hence why the 'turn' methods are boolean). User will repeat that process multiple times until they achieve the correct combo and can open the lock, so no variables there should be FINAL either.

Comment: I don't any chance of a loop here. You only have one call to turnFirstNumber() and turnSecondNumber(). What's your evidence that they are being called more than once? I suspect you have a different version where you are retrying, but you haven't shown us that.

Comment: that's why I posted this. When I run the program it keeps looping between those two methods lol. I did not include my FULL code to try and maintain an SSCCE, and I think this bit that I have included should have the error somewhere because these are the only segments causing me trouble

Comment: This is for people who don't have a LIVE

Comment: I think this will continue to be hard to debug until you follow @mike's advice and rewrite it -- see how similar the `turnXNumber` methods are? In reorganising the code you may well find that you remove or begin to understand the problem. The essence of programming is abstraction.

Comment: Dunno where you going with that code - but that can be a login form alternative, which could be awesome!

Comment: @eric.itzhak, point me in the right direction man. I'm just a beginner here trying to get my CS degree

Comment: @AlexMarsh Sry, but you already have constants in your program. For example `40` and `39`. It's not clear what these numbers mean to others, and also if you want do change them in future, it would be better if you use a variable (with a clear name). So you could change it in a single place **and** thereby you would also update all the other occurrences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it's looping?

In your openLock method it's calling the methods **turnFirstNumber**, **turnSecondNumber** and **turnThirdNumber** in every if-statement.

In case *the last number* is incorrect, it has called the methods **turnFirstNumber**, **turnSecondNumber** and **turnThirdNumber** each 5 times.

I think it's better to introduce variables like **firstTurnCorrect**, **secondTurnCorrect** and **thirdTurnCorrect** and compare those values to get the right message:

```
boolean firstTurnCorrect = turnFirstNumber();
boolean secondTurnCorrect = turnSecondNumber();
boolean thirdTurnCorrect = turnThirdNumber();

if (!firstTurnCorrect && secondTurnCorrect && thirdTurnCorrect) ...
```

This way those methods only gets called once.

Comment: So the way I've written the openLock() method, instead of checking to see if the results of turnFirstNumber(), turnSecondNumber(), and turnThirdNumber() are true/false, it runs each method and then checks if theyre true/false? That is definitely the issue then.